# 2 Email addresses for each user

Tags: email, user-registration

Is there a way to let a user who registers an account in WP add 2 email addresses that will be associated with that account?

The reason for the required function: We have a website that sells online courses that will be used by High School students. Normally the parent will do the registration because they will also need to do a credit card payment to buy courses.
So we would like to have the main account address to be the parent's, and then a second address that will be the student's.

We're using WP Courseware for the courses. Once we have implemented the 2 addresses on the accounts, we want to update the WP Courseware plugin to also send all course notifications to both the parent and student.

Answer (score 0):

You can create usermeta at time of insert user
like, i create zip code in my site see this code,

```
$user_id = wp_insert_user(
                            array(
                                'user_login'    =>  $user_email,
                                'user_pass'     =>  wp_generate_password ( 12, false ),
                                'first_name'    =>  'khushu',
                                'last_name'     =>  'soni',
                                'user_email'    =>  $user_email,
                                'display_name'  =>  'khushu' . ' ' . 'soni',
                                'nickname'      =>  'khushu' . ' ' . 'soni',
                                'role'          =>  'Subscriber'
                            )
                        );
                        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'zip_code', '56789' );
```